# Crystal Report 2008: Advanced Graph/Chart - data in x axis is a numeric value of seconds, is it possible to convert this into a HH:MM:SS time?

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-2008

Essentially I have a graph on my report. See attached image. The X axis is a duration in seconds. It is possible in Crystal 2008 to get the bar graph segments to have a label with the converted seconds to HH:MM:SS? Essentially turning 60 seconds into 00:01:00 on the label?

[image]

Comment: are you using tables or query in reports?

Comment: tables. connected to an ODBC connection.